# Unnesting Node database calls

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, nested

I have an ordinary

```
var express = require('express')
```

Node express www page, using session, pug, etc as usual. My db calls

```
var db = require('./scripts/myHappyMysqlScript')
```

I'm naturally using `mysql`, so in the db script

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
```

So for example

```
app.get('/catPhotos', (req, response) => {
    response.render('catPhotos.pug');
})
```

Say a page has a table showing something from the petNames database,

```
app.get('/pets', function(req, res, next) {
    db.allPetNames(function(err, petsList) {
        res.render('pets.pug',
            {
                'petsList': petsList,
                'pretty' : true
            })
    })
```

all good so far.

But here's a case with **three tables** on the pug page, and three different database calls:

```
db.cats(function(err, c) {
    db.dogs(function(err, d) {
        db.budgies(function(err, b) {
            res.render('bigScreen.pug',
                {
                    'cats' : c,
                    'k9s': d,
                    'budgies': b,
                    'pretty' : true
                })
        })
    })
})
```

I just nest them like that.

**This does seem to work perfectly.**

It correctly waits sequentially.  Errors fall through and are handled properly, and so on.

But is there a better syntax, better way?
What's the Node Way for real™ Node, not-Swift, programmers?!

Perhaps given that I'm using the `mysql` library, if that's relevant.

---

*Note, one better way overall is to use something like Ajax to just stream in each "part" of the web page.  Indeed I do that all the time.  What I'm asking here, assuming at res.render I indeed want to return all that info at once, is there something better than nesting like that?  Cheers*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get rid of nested database calls by using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Since you mentioned that you are using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) library for interacting with the database, unfortunately, this library doesn't provide a promise-based API. So to get rid of nested database calls in your code, you need to create a promise-based wrapper around the callback version of database calls.

For a general overview of what promises are and how they work, see the following links:

- [MDN - Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
- [MDN - Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Following is an example of how you can create a promise-based wrapper and then use that wrapper to get rid of nested database calls.

This promise-based wrapper is just a function that returns a promise. It creates a promise instance, wraps the underlying database call, and eventually when the database call returns the data, it notifies your code.

```
function getCats() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // make the database call
       db.cats((error, cats) => {
           // in case of an error, reject the promise by
           // calling "reject" function
           // Also pass the "error" object to the "reject" function
           // as an argument to get access to the error message 
           // in the code that calls this "getCats" function
           if (error) {
              reject(error);
              return;
           }
           
           // if there was no error, call the "resolve" function
           // to resolve the promise. Promise will be resolved 
           // in case of a successful database call
           // Also pass the data to the "resolve" function
           // to access this data in the code that calls this
           // "getCats" function
           resolve(cats);
       });
   });
}
```

Now in your route handler function, instead of calling `db.cats(...)`, call this `getCats` wrapper function.

There are two ways you can call the function that returns a promise:

- `Promise-chaining`    (For details, visit the links mentioned above)
- `async-await` syntax  (Recommended)

The following code example uses `async-await` syntax. For this, first, mark the route handler function as `async` by using the `async` keyword before the `function` keyword. By doing this, we can use the `await` keyword inside this route handler function.

```
app.get('/pets', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
       const cats = await getCats();
       // similar wrappers for other database calls
       const dogs = await getDogs();
       const budgies = await getBudgies();
       
       // render the pub template, passing in the data
       // fetched from the database 
       ...

     catch (error) {
       // catch block will be invoked if the promise returned by
       // the promise-based wrapper function is rejected
       // handle the error appropriately
     }
});
```

The above code example only shows how to wrap the `db.cats(...)` database call in a promise-based wrapper and use that wrapper to get the data from the database. Similarly, you can create wrappers for `db.dogs(...)` and `db.budgies(...)` calls.

Instead of creating a separate promise-based wrapper for each database call, ideally, **you should create a re-usable promise-based wrapper function** that takes in a function to call and wraps that function call in a promise just like shown in the above code example, i.e. `getCats` function.

#### Parallel Database calls

One important thing to note in the above code is the route handler function

```
const cats = await getCats();
const dogs = await getDogs();
const budgies = await getBudgies();
```

is that this will lead to **sequential database calls** which may or may not be what you want.

If these database calls do not depend on each other, then you can call the promise-based wrappers in parallel using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method.

The following code example shows how you can call your promise-based wrapper functions in parallel using `Promise.all()`.

```
app.get('/pets', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
       // "petsData" will be an array that will contain all the data from 
       // three database calls.
       const petsData = await Promise.all([getCats(), getDogs(), getBudgies()]);
       
       // render the pub template, passing in the data
       // fetched from the database 
       ...
 
     catch (error) {
       ...
     }
 });
```

I hope this is enough to help you get rid of the nested database calls in your current code and start using promises in your code.

Comment: That still feels like chaining.  I think of step 1 is get data, step 2 is rendering.  But even the Promise-based code seems to bury the rendering code _inside_ the get-data code instead of _after_ it.

Comment: @RickJames _"even the Promise-based code seems to bury the rendering code inside the get-data code instead of after it"_ - if you look at the code in the `try` block inside the callback function of the route handler, you will see the two steps you mentioned at the start of your comment. Promise-based code is just concerned with getting the data from the database and the rendering code is _after_ the data fetching code. There's a comment in the `try` block where the rendering code should be written.

Comment: That's what I thought.   There are times when I want to do a lot of processing, including some number of SQL calls.  I would like to have a `function` that reaches out to the database and comes back with the data.  Since I need the results before preceding, I don't even need "async".

Comment: `Parallel Database calls` This is the way. Very clean, easy to maintain, and flexible. With Promise.all it will fail fast if any of the calls fail. You could look at other Promise options and potentially support a case when you have a partial failure and still do a partial render.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to use MySQL with Nodejs, the module you should be looking for is `mysql2` rather than `mysql`.

`mysql2` provides a promise based approach and is a much refined version of `mysql` module for nodejs.

For example, for executing a query,

1. in `mysql`

```
con.query(sql_query, (err, rows, field)=>{ //some code here }
```

2. in `mysql2`, you can use the async approach as well as promise approach. Also, prepared statements in mysql2 are more easier than mysql.

```
//async approach
class A {
   static async fn(sql, params){
      const [data] = await con.execute(sql, [params]);
    return data;
    }
}

//promise approach remains same as **mysql** itself.
```

Here's the documentation for
[mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) & [more docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/sqlstring)

Answer (score 1):

If your database calls returned promises instead of using callbacks, you could:

```js
const cats = await db.cats();
const dogs = await db.dogs();
const budgies = await db.budgies();

res.render('bigScreen.pug', {
  cats : cats,
  k9s: dogs,
  budgies: budgies,
  pretty : true
});


// Or request them all in parallel instead of waiting for each to finish
const [
  cats,
  dogs,
  budgies
] = Promise.all([
  dg.cats(),
  dg.dogs(),
  db.budgies()
]);
```

Comment: Dylan, thanks, I'm using the 'mysql' library, so ... ?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert the mysql functions into promises using the nodejs standard lib `util.promisify`

example:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const catsPromise = promisify(db.cats);
const dogsPromise = promisify(db.dogs);
const budgiesPromise = promisify(db.budgies);

async function routeHandler() {
  let err = null;

  try {
    const cats = await catsPromise();
    const dogs = await dogsPromise();
    const budgies = await budgiesPromise();
  } catch(error) {
    err = error;
  }

  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // you should res.end() or res.render(someErrorPage) here
    // failure to do so will leave the request open
  } else {
    res.render('bigScreen.pug', {
      'cats' : cats,
      'k9s': dogs,
      'budgies': budgies,
      'pretty' : true
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all()` method seems a more famous and cleaner way to make multiple calls in parallel like your use case.

But there is one more alternate way. : **[Multiple statement queries](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries)**

To use this feature you have to enable it for your connection:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

Once enabled, you can execute multiple statement queries like any other query:

```
db.query('SELECT cats; SELECT dogs', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // `results` is an array with one element for every statement in the query:
  console.log(results[0]); // [{cat1,cat2}]
  console.log(results[1]); // [{dog1,dog2}]
});
```

It is technically more efficient as requires less back and forth with MySQL connection.

(However, this feature is disabled by default as it allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not properly escaped). To use this feature you have to enable it for your connection.)