# How to handle a full pool of mysql connections in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my Node script I use MySQL and to be able to handle multiple connections I use a connection pool.

Today I forgot to release a connection in the mysql pool. It took me a long time to figure out what the problem was because there was no error shown anywhere.

My code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'x',
    user     : 'x',
    password : '#x',
    database : 'x',
    connectionLimit: 2
  });

function executeQuery(){
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        let query = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", 1);

        connection.query(query, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log(rows);
        });
    });
}

executeQuery(); // outputs the user as expected
executeQuery(); // outputs the user as expected
executeQuery(); // there is no output in the console, it just looks like nothing happened
```

My question: How to find out if there are still connections available and if there are no connection available anymore show an error or handle it in a different way?

Comment: Don't do `mysql.format`, instead just use placeholder values, like `conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?', [1], ...)`. Also look at using a library like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) that supports promises because callback code can get severely ugly.

Comment: I think you have to use ```mysql2``` rather than using ```mysql```;\n
Why mysql2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464555/unnesting-node-database-calls/65138795#65138795
 
Here's the link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#first-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `release` your connection:

```js
function executeQuery(){
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [ 1 ], (err, rows) => {
            connection.release(); // Give it back or else it gets lost

            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

There's also no reason to grab the connection like that, you can just use the pool:

```js
function executeQuery() {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [ 1 ], (err, connection) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(rows);
    });
}
```

Comment: I know I did, that's what I already mentioned in my question. The problem was that it took me a huge amount of time to find out that was the problem. Because my limit was 10 and it worked all the time when I was testing it, but when there were more then 10 connections it stopped working and I didn't know it had anything todo with the database at all.

Comment: The `mysql` NPM package is really, to put it politely, rudimentary. You'll want to use something better if you're building anything non-trivial. As for the connection issue, there's no way to inspect the pool. The idea is that you should *always* return connections or else things get weird. The second form here makes it impossible to forget.

Comment: So in the second form I don't need to close the connection myself?

Comment: The second form automatically returns the connection to the pool the instant that operation completes, so yes, it's basically impossible to foul up. In your first version you must be sure to return it regardless of the error situation. It is easy to inadvertently return it *conditionally* which is where difficult to resolve bugs come about.