# How do I return a value for a non promise callback inside an async fucntion

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In below Node.js function, how do I return data.QueueUrl, so that a caller can get the value with

```
var url = await createSubscription('foo', req);
```

This is the function

```
async function createSubscription(name, req){
  var params = {
    QueueName: name,
    Attributes: {
        'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': '20', // long polling wait time
    }
  };
  sqs.createQueue(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error("createQueue error : " + err, req);
    } else {
      logger.log("queue " + name + ' created', req);
      return data.QueueUrl;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Wrap `sqs.createQueue` in a promise constructor. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464555/unnesting-node-database-calls/64465915#64465915. Easiest way to dos this is via `Util` module: `const promisifiedFn = Util.promisify(sqs.createQueue);`

Comment: Surprisingly that didn't work for me. I got an exception calling the promisified function for createQueue. This worked though


const response = await sqs.createQueue(params).promise();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Best practice is to wrap problematic functions at the lowest possible level, and then never call them directly again - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#creating_a_promise_around_an_old_callback_api)

For you this means doing the following:

```
function createQueue(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sqs.createQueue(params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data));
  });
}
```

After that you can work with `createQueue` instead of `sqs.createQueue`:

```
async function createSubscription(name, req) {
  const params = {
    QueueName: name,
    Attributes: {
        'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': '20', // long polling wait time
    }
  };

  try {
    const data = await createQueue(params);
    logger.log("queue " + name + ' created', req);
    return data.QueueUrl;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error("createQueue error : " + err, req);
    // you'll probably want to re-throw here unless the caller knows
    // that an undefined return value means an error has occurred
  }
}
```

Without all the additional log statements, the function can also look like this:

```
async function createSubscription(name, req) {
  const params = {
    QueueName: name,
    Attributes: {
        'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': '20', // long polling wait time
    }
  };

  const data = await createQueue(params);
  return data.QueueUrl;
}
```

Since we don't use a try/catch the error/rejected promise bubbles up to the caller.

---

Since all the SQS functions are in the style `sqs.function(params, callback)` (see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html)), you could also write a more general helper that works on all the SQS functions.

```
function sqsPromise(sqsFnName, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sqs[sqsFnName](params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data));
  });
}
```

Which allows you to do:

```
const data = await sqsPromise("createQueue", params);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't need to be `async` to create and return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
function createSubscription (name, req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      QueueName: name,
      Attributes: {'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': '20'}
    };
  
    sqs.createQueue(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        logger.error('createQueue error : ' + err, req);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        logger.log('queue ' + name + ' created', req);
        resolve(data.QueueUrl);
      }
    });
  });
}

const url = await createSubscription('foo', req);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function to return a Promise and resolve and reject the required data according to your logic. The other way is to promisfy your callback using the util module.

Answer (score 0):

Write your function like this to return a promise

```
async function createSubscription(name, req){
    try{
        const params = {
          QueueName: name,
          Attributes: {
              'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': '20', // long polling wait time
          }
        };

        let data = await sqs.createQueue(params).promise();
        return data;
    }
    catch(err){
        logger.error("createQueue error : " + err.message);
    }
}
```

And call it like this to receive the value

```
const url = await createSubscription('foo', req);
console.log(url.QueueUrl); // You'll get the result in url variable.
```

Comment: This returned me some sqs request object. I believe reason being that sqs.createQueue is not a promise

Comment: I've changed the code. check again and let me know if it's working or not @Stubborn

Comment: `catch` block should throw the error to avoid [implicit conversion of promise rejection into fulfilment](https://yousaf.hashnode.dev/common-promise-anti-patterns#heading-converting-promise-rejection-in-to-fulfilment). Alternatively, you could remove the `try-catch` from the function and do the error handling in the code that calls this function.

Comment: @KhalidKhan What did you change? I still can't call sqs.createQueue with await if it is not a promise, right?

Comment: @Stubborn oh I didn't add the promise. check now