javascript MySQL - using Promise-await-async constructs, can't get code to wait for query completion
I've tried multiple versions of example code but can never seem to get something that guarantees completion of the query set before other code commences.  I was under the impression that 'await' makes the query complete before continuing.
I'm running my javascript with node.js in Webstorm. The code below inserts three rows into the table 'Verb' in the DB  'ItalianVerbs'.  I've tried it with a couple different conditions.  The first condition is where I have the last lines of code 'g_con.end();' and 'process.exit(0);' commented out. If I start it and just let it run this way, it finishes the calls quickly, but the program does not exit, and the table lines are successfully entered into the database - but, the order of the log messages indicate things are running asynchronously.
The second condition is where I un-comment the 'process.exit(0)' call at the end - in which case I see the log messages from the 'USE' queries, but none from the INSERT queries, which indicates that nothing is being waited for and the program exits before those threads complete.
This is making me a bit nuts - ultimately I want a block of code that I can encapsulate in a function, and have all the queries started in that function complete before the function returns.
My code below, cobbled up from multiple other examples.
const mysql = require('mysql');

const selectedDB = 'ItalianVerbs';
const str_VerbCols = " (infinitive, english, auxiliary, gerund, participle)";

const g_con = mysql.createConnection(
   {
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'Kl1n&on0per@',
      database: selectedDB
   });

//============================================================================
// SECOND STEP USING MYSQL - select a specific database to use.
//============================================================================

function f_use_db(con, db_name) {
   let qry = 'USE ' + db_name + ';';            // qry = 'USE ItalianVerbs'
   con.query(qry, (err, pkt) => {
      if (err) { throw err;}
   });
   return qry;
}

//============================================================================
// Build query string for INSERT ROW into Verb table.
//============================================================================

function f_query_for_verb_tbl(val_list) {
   if (val_list.length < 5) {
      console.log("[f_insert_info_Verb_row] - ERROR: not enough values for inserted row\n")
      return -1;
   }

   let qry = 'INSERT INTO Verb' + str_VerbCols + ' VALUES (';
   val_list.forEach(function (v, idx) {
      qry = qry + '"' + v + '"';
      if (idx < 4)
         qry = qry + ', ';
   })

   qry = qry + ');';
   return qry;
}

//============================================================================

qPromise1 = async () => {
   const query =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let qry = f_use_db(g_con, selectedDB, false);
      console.log('*** RUNNING QUERY: ' + qry);
      g_con.query(qry, (err, res) => {                  // q = 'USE ItalianVerbs'
         if (err) { return reject(err); }
         return resolve(res);
      });
   });

   await query;
}

//============================================================================

qPromise2 = async (v_q) => {                          // v_q is INSERT query string.
   console.log('*** RUNNING QUERY: ' + v_q);
   const query = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      g_con.query(v_q, (err, res) => {
         if (err) { return reject(err); }
         return resolve(res);
      });
   });

   await query;
}

//============================================================================

async function sequentialQueries (qry) {
   try {
      const r1 = await qPromise1();
      const r2 = await qPromise2(qry);
   }
   catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return(err);
   }

   return 0;
}

//============================================================================
//============================================================================

let nvd1 = ["adorare", "adore", "avere", "adorando", "adorato"];
let nvd2 = ["abitare", "dwell", "avere", "abitando", "abitato"];
let nvd3 = ["abbassare", "let-down", "avere", "abbandonando", "abbandonato"]

let lvd_list = [nvd1, nvd2, nvd3];

g_con.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) { console.log('error on connect to MySql - ' + err); }
});

lvd_list.forEach(function (v) {
   let v_qry = f_query_for_verb_tbl(v);
   let rval = sequentialQueries(v_qry);
})

// g_con.end();
console.log('exiting');
// process.exit(0);


You need to promisify f_use_db and g_con.connect functions as well. Alternatively, you can use another library that provides promise-based API. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464555/unnesting-node-database-calls/64465915#64465915

Also, await each function that returns a promise and instead of using forEach method that doesn't work with await, use for of loop.

You need to change your code to something like this for it to work. I have refactored it to make it work like you expect it to. Haven't tested it but it should give you an idea of what you need to do. Also, I have used node's builtin util.promisify method instead of the promise constructor but the idea is the same, promisify function is just a bit more convenient to use.

I think u should use mysql2 package, it allows you to execute queries asynchronously

Unfortunately mysql2 does not seem to work with Node V12.  Any examples I have tried throw weird 'Unexpected token' faults.  I'm at wits-end here

I suggest you to use Sequelize. It is a Node.js ORM tool for Postgres, MySQL, etc. You can create your instance like that: const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname') // Example for postgres. But answering your question could be due to your last foreach.
In JavaScript, using async/await within a forEach loop may not work as expected due to how asynchronous operations are handled in JavaScript. async/await works well with for or while loops, but forEach doesn't wait for asynchronous functions to complete before moving on to the next iteration. You can use a for...of loop instead to properly handle asynchronous operations within the loop. Do you need an example of how to do it with for...of?

I have tried every method here, using examples I found online.  None of them work, I suspect the problem is with the version of node.js (V12.22.9)/  There seems to be a known issue with mysql2 and this later version of node,js, and since Sequelize runs on top of MySQL2, it has the same errors.  Even this simple DigitalOcean example:( https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sequelize-with-node-js-and-mysql ) fails with the 'Unexpected token' error.

Please try below approach:
for (let v of lvd_list) {
   let v_qry = f_query_for_verb_tbl(v);
   let rval = await sequentialQueries(v_qry);
}

Also, modify qPromise1 and qPromise2 as below:
qPromise1 = ()=> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let qry = f_use_db(g_con, selectedDB, false);
      console.log('*** RUNNING QUERY: ' + qry);
      g_con.query(qry, (err, res) => {                  
         if (err) { return reject(err); }
         return resolve(res);
      });
   });
}


qPromise2 = (v_q)=> {                          
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('*** RUNNING QUERY: ' + v_q);
      g_con.query(v_q, (err, res) => {
         if (err) { return reject(err); }
         return resolve(res);
      });
   });
}


unfortunately this made no difference.

@user55836 please modify qPromise1 and qPromise2 along with for of loop
